# Django/Apache2 ALLOWED_HOSTS settings doesn't work

Tags: django, apache2, domain-name

I have my ALLOWED_HOSTS configured as below in my settings.py file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost',
    'semanticspace.io',
    'www.semanticspace.io'
]
```

I also configured apache2 ServerName as below:

```
...
ServerName semanticspace.io
ServerAlias www.semanticspace.io
...
```

Despite these, when I try to access my web page it gives this error:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.semanticspace.io'. You may need to add 'www.semanticspace.io' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

What might be the cause of that?

Comment: Have you restarted django/apache since the change to your settings?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought of restarting apache as it seemed irrelevant. Now it works.